# Discord Bot was working when i made it now is not working?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

well i made this discord bot yesterday it was working like charm now today i got something that the button was give me errors

this is the error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yosbel.Gonzalez001\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\Yosbel.Gonzalez001\Downloads\Bots\Registracion Discord Bot\main.py", line 42, in registration_button
    user = interaction.user
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I tried to do some changes i went to ubuntu and the codes work but on windows didnt work any more

this is the part of the code that may need attention

```
 @discord.ui.button(label="Registración", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def registration_button(self, button: Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user
        if user.id in pending_registrations:
            await user.send("Ya estás en proceso de registro.")
        else:
            pending_registrations[user.id] = {"step": 1}
            await user.send("Por favor, introduce tu correo electrónico:")
```